# Twilio lookup test numbers

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

[There are test numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-sms-messages-parameters-To) to which you can send SMS using [my test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/dev-tools/test-credentials). They fake sending beautifully. But, attempting to use the [lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-query-parameters) also provided by Twilio, even if the intention is to retrieve information about the [test number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024936/test-telephone-numbers-for-twilio), will fail:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from twilio.rest.lookups import TwilioLookupsClient
>>> account_sid = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
>>> auth_token = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
>>> client = TwilioLookupsClient(account_sid, auth_token)
>>> lookup_client.phone_numbers.get('+15005555009', include_carrier_info=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TwilioRestException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-03718f1c0615> in <module>()
----> 1 client.phone_numbers.get('+15005555009', include_carrier_info=True)

...

TwilioRestException: 
HTTP Error Your request was:

GET https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+15005555009?Type=carrier

Twilio returned the following information:

Resource not accessible with Test Account Credentials

More information may be available here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20008
```

+15005555009 is the only phone number listed to emulate a landline, that is incapable of returning an SMS. I am expecting the API to return 'landline' for the carrier type for such a number. [That link in the error message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20008) brings me to a page with no working test credentials.

How can I test the lookup API with the test credentials given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can use the lookup API with test credentials.

From https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials ...

"Supported Resources

Your test credentials can currently be used to interact with the following three resources:

- Buying phone numbers: `POST
  /2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers`
- Sending SMS messages: `POST
  /2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/SMS/Messages`
- Making calls: `POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/Calls`

Requests to any other resource with test credentials will receive a 403 Forbidden response. In the future, we may enable these resources for testing as well."

Comment: Dang. Thanks anyway!